# Cross product using the checker method

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw an old question on how to obtain arrows inside of matrices using arrows. And thanks to Altermundus I was able to hack together the file below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{|rrr|rr}
i &  j & k & i &  j\\
3 & -2 & 2 & 3 & -2\\
3 &  2 & 1 & 3 &  2
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\tikzset{node style ge/.style={circle}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
  \tikzset{BarreStyle/.style =   {opacity=.4,line width=3 mm,line cap=round,color=#1}}
  \tikzset{SignePlus/.style  =   {above left,,opacity=0.8,circle,fill=#1!50}}
  \tikzset{SigneMoins/.style =   {above right,,opacity=0.8,circle,fill=#1!50}}
% les matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},,column sep=0 mm] 
{      i &  j & k & i &  j \\
       3 & -2 & 2 & 3 & -2 \\
       3 &  2 & 1 & 3 &  2 \\
};

 \draw [BarreStyle=red] (A-1-1.north west) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (A-3-3.south east) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=red] (A-1-2.north west) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (A-3-4.south east) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=red] (A-1-3.north west) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (A-3-5.south east) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (A-1-3.north east) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (A-3-1.south west);
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (A-1-4.north east) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (A-3-2.south west);
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (A-1-5.north east) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (A-3-3.south west);
 \draw (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west); \draw (A-1-3.north east) -- (A-3-3.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: CrossProduct]

Now I am having a few bunks to iron out, and some help would be much obliged =)

- Is there any method to get the absolute signs, eg the brackets `| |` around the matrices to be horizontal? Right now they are slanted, due to the different size of `a_{11}` and `$_{13}`.
- The blue and red lines are also not quite parallel, any fix here?

I was thinking of wrapping this code in a new environment, or something. But I guess that will have to do for a later question. I sort of need to make a few of these, so I would preffer not a quick and dirty fix that works only in this case. My entries are never bigger than 3 digits.

Comment: The best is *never* teach the "Sarrus' rule". If one learns it, good for him/her. But when a student will apply the rule to 4x4 matrices, the fault will be only on the teacher. Developing the determinant over the first row is just as easy.

Comment: I try to show several methods. I must say I prefer cofactor expansion. But also one an never get enough practice in tikz! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some modifications that can (hopefully) improve the result:

1. I declared a fixed width for the text in the matrix nodes.
2. I used the `let` syntax to draw the vertical rules.
3. I reduced the `inner sep` value for the nodes containing the signs.
4. I defined a `\checkers` command with a mandatory argument (the name of the matrix) to draw the design. In fact, a seven argument command might be used for the whole construct.

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}

\newcommand\checkers[1]{%
 \draw [BarreStyle=red] (#1-1-1.120) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (#1-3-3.320) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=red] (#1-1-2.120) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (#1-3-4.320) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=red] (#1-1-3.120) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (#1-3-5.320) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (#1-1-3.35) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (#1-3-1.230);
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (#1-1-4.35) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (#1-3-2.230);
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (#1-1-5.35) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (#1-3-3.230);
 \draw let \p1 = (#1-3-3.south east), \p2 = ( $ (#1-1-3.north east)!.5!(#1-1-4.north) $ ) in (\p2) -- (\x2,\y1);
 \draw let \p1 = (#1-1-1.north west), \p2 = (#1-3-1.south west) in (\p2) -- (\x2,\y1);
}
\tikzset{BarreStyle/.style =   {opacity=.4,line width=4mm,line cap=round,color=#1}}
\tikzset{SignePlus/.style  =   {above left,,opacity=0.8,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=#1!50}}
\tikzset{SigneMoins/.style =   {above right,,opacity=0.8,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=#1!50}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{node style ge/.style={circle}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},column sep=0 mm,nodes={text width=1em,align=right}] 
{      i &  j & k & i &  j \\
       3 & -2 & 2 & 3 & -2 \\
       31 &  2 & 61 & 3 &  2 \\
};
\checkers{A}
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(B.center)]
\matrix (B) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},column sep=0 mm,nodes={text width=1em,align=right}] 
{      i &  j & k & i &  j \\
       13 & -2 & 25 & 13 & -2 \\
       3 &  -18 & 1 & 3 &  2 \\
};
\checkers{B}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this will be always used to indicate cross-products, then a command with seven arguments (the six coordinates and the matrix name) can be defined; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}

\newcommand\checkers[7]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(#1.center)]
\tikzset{BarreStyle/.style =   {opacity=.4,line width=4mm,line cap=round,color=##1}}
\tikzset{SignePlus/.style  =   {above left,opacity=0.8,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=##1!50}}
\tikzset{SigneMoins/.style =   {above right,opacity=0.8,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=##1!50}}
\tikzset{node style ge/.style={circle}}

\matrix (#1) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},column sep=0 mm,nodes={text width=1.8em,align=right,font=\footnotesize},ampersand replacement = \&] 
{      i \&  j \& k \& i \&  j \\
       #2 \& #3 \& #4 \& #2 \& #3 \\
       #5 \&  #6 \& #7 \& #5 \&  #6 \\
};
\draw [BarreStyle=red] (#1-1-1.120) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (#1-3-3.320) ;
\draw [BarreStyle=red] (#1-1-2.120) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (#1-3-4.320) ;
\draw [BarreStyle=red] (#1-1-3.120) node[SignePlus=red] {$+$} to (#1-3-5.320) ;
\draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (#1-1-3.35) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (#1-3-1.230);
\draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (#1-1-4.35) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (#1-3-2.230);
\draw [BarreStyle=blue]  (#1-1-5.35) node[SigneMoins=blue] {$-$} to (#1-3-3.230);
\draw let \p1 = (#1-3-3.south east), \p2 = ( $ (#1-1-3.north east)!.5!(#1-1-4.north) $ ) in (\p2) -- (\x2,\y1);
\draw let \p1 = (#1-1-1.north west), \p2 = (#1-3-1.south west) in (\p2) -- (\x2,\y1);\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\checkers{A}{3}{-2}{2}{31}{2}{61}\\[1em]
\checkers{B}{13}{-2}{25}{3}{-18}{1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really great! Is the only reason to post to images to show that it works with double digit numbers? =) I tried seeing if there are any differences, and I can not spot any,

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar yes; I only wanted to show that it behaves relatively well in more than one case ;-)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I've updated my answer with a command to simplify the code.

Answer (score 6):

Just another solution using `fit`, `rotate fit` and `pgfonlayer`...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds,fit}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\checkers[1]{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \tikzset{
      bar style/.style={inner ysep=-.1em,inner xsep=1em,rounded corners=.8em},
      fillop/.style={fill=##1,fill opacity=.3},
      sign/.style={circle,inner sep=.2em,fillop=##1,text opacity=1},
    }
    \foreach \posa in {1,2,3}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\posb}{\posa + 2}
      \node[bar style=red,rotate fit=-45,
      fit=(#1-1-\posa)(#1-3-\posb),fillop=red,
      label={[sign=red]west:$+$}]{};
      \node[bar style=red,rotate fit=45,
      fit=(#1-1-\posb)(#1-3-\posa),fillop=blue,
      label={[sign=blue]east:$-$}]{};
    }
    \draw let \p1=($(#1-1-3)!.5!(#1-1-4)$) in
    (\p1 |- #1.north) -- (\p1 |- #1.south);
    \draw (#1.north west) -- (#1.south west);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (A)
  [matrix of math nodes,inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum size=2.5em,inner sep=0pt}] 
  {
    i  & j  & k  & i & j  \\
    3  & -2 & 2  & 3 & -2 \\
    61 & 2  & 61 & 3 & 2  \\
  };
  \checkers{A}
\end{tikzpicture}

{\footnotesize%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (B)
    [matrix of math nodes,inner sep=0pt,
    nodes={minimum size=2.5em,inner sep=0pt}] 
    {
      i  & j   & k  & i  & j  \\
      13 & -2  & 125 & 13 & -2 \\
      3  & -18 & 1  & 3  & 2  \\
    };
    \checkers{B}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Here is results with different font sizes:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Unfortunately I'm out of votes for today.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very sexy, but easy.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
 \tikzset{BarreStyle/.style ={opacity=.4,line width=4 mm,line cap=round,color=#1!50}}
 \tikzset{SignePlus/.style = {above left,,opacity=1,circle,fill=#1!20}}
 \tikzset{SigneMoins/.style =   {below left,,opacity=1,circle,fill=#1!20}}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},,column sep=0 mm] 
{ \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} \\
  \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} \\
 \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} \\
 \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} \\
  \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} & \phantom{A} \\
};

 \draw [BarreStyle=blue] (A-1-1.north west) to (A-3-3.south east);
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue] (A-2-1.north west) to (A-4-3.south east) ;
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue] (A-3-1.north west) to (A-5-3.south east) ;

 \draw [BarreStyle=red]  (A-3-1.south west)  to (A-1-3.north east);
 \draw [BarreStyle=red]  (A-4-1.south west)  to (A-2-3.north east);
 \draw [BarreStyle=red]  (A-5-1.south west)  to (A-3-3.north east);

 \draw (A-1-1.north west) node[SignePlus=blue] {$+$};
 \draw (A-2-1.north west) node[SignePlus=blue] {$+$};
 \draw (A-3-1.north west) node[SignePlus=blue] {$+$};
 \draw (A-3-1.south west) node[SigneMoins=red] {$-$};
 \draw (A-4-1.south west) node[SigneMoins=red] {$-$};
 \draw (A-5-1.south west) node[SigneMoins=red] {$-$};

 \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},,column sep=0 mm] 
 { a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
   g & h & i \\
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
```